# Goodbye grand mother <3

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, real

My grand-mother died the 17th of June 20 from cancer after spending the last three months nearly alone in her house because of the COVID Pandemic. I dedicate her this puzzle. She's Lao and today, for her funerals, we have prepared 100 little gifts that'll be given to the 100 hundred guests, family and friends that'll come tomorrow to say our last goodbye.

[image]

Under the two tables my uncle put water under each table's foot as you can see in the photos I took.

[image]

#### This puzzle is to discover why he did that!

IMPORTANT: I want people that already knew the answer of this puzzle before seeing it, because for example they already did that on a funeral or somehow else to let people try finding out. After 1 week or two, if no one that didn't already know the answer finds it, then anyone will be allowed to answer. That is, the knowledge tag could be present only in two weeks :) Thanks! Happy puzzling!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m so sorry for your loss, friend. May your grandmother rest peacefully.

Comment: @El-Guest, thank you a lot :) I'd like that it is the only comment for the community to say sorry for me as the aim is still to puzzle here. If you want to say sorry you can upvote it :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sorry for your loss.

> Are the plates with water placed so that the walking insects (like ants) do not get to the gifts?